# How to extend a defined response in OpenAPI?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I want to extend the "200SuccessDefault" response with a schema or example.

```yaml
paths:
  /home:
      ...
      responses:
        200:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/200SuccessDefault'
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/PieChartElement'
              examples:
                PieChart:
                  $ref: '#/components/examples/PieChart_1'
```

This approach runs into an error, the `schema` and `examples` fields are ignored:

> Sibling values alongside $refs are ignored. To add properties to a $ref, wrap the $ref into allOf, or move the extra properties into the referenced definition (if applicable).

I tried `allOf`:

```yaml
paths:
  /home:
      responses:
        200:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/responses/200SuccessDefault'
            - content:
                application/json:
                  schema:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/PieChartElement'
                  examples:
                    PieChart:
                      $ref: '#/components/examples/PieChart_1'
```

This approach runs into the error:

> should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: allOf
> should have required property 'description' missingProperty: description

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You **cannot extend a referenced response** object. But, you can use a **shared schema object** and extend it utilizing **allOf within schema**.

Inside allOf you can put:

- your $ref
- a new type **extending your default response**

If you want to give an example of an entire extended response (JSON), just put it into "application/json".

An example of OpenAPI would be:

```
    "202":
      description: Extended response sample
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            allOf:
              - $ref: "#/components/schemas/application"
              - type: object
                properties:
                  anotherProperty:
                    type: string
                    maxLength: 200
                    example: "Property example"
          example: {id: 1234, anotherProperty: "Hello"}
```

Comment: What if I dont want to define a description and wnat the description to be inherited, is this possible?

Comment: Its not exactly what I want. I dont want to reference the schemas. I want to reference the whole "202" object.

Comment: @sg_rs you can't use response components in `allOf`. Here's an existing feature request: [Compose all component types, not just schemas](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2936)